# WordPress twenty twelve,How to output the first 2 words from wp_title?

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello stackoverflow ,

I am using wp_title  to output the title of the page,but some titles are too long.

Can anyone explain me how to write the function to return only first 2 words of the title ?

Img exemple: Thank You .

```
  <?php  wp_title('');  ?>
```

And here is [image: img]

Answer (score 2):

```
//use this code in functions.php file
  add_filter('wp_title', set_page_title($message));

  function set_page_title($message) { 
     $message = explode(' ', $message, 2);
     $message = implode(' ', $message);
    //Here I can echo the result and see that it's actually triggered
    return $message;  
  }
```

Comment: it wont work ,and I belive i need to use substr,thank you tho